# Nested entity collection

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I've got a scenario where I'm trying to have a growable hierarchy of a same-type nested collection for a specific purpose and I'm using **EF Core 2.2**.

```
public class Group:Entity
{
    public Group(Guid id):base(id)
    {
    }
   ...
   public List<Group> SubGroups { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Entity
{
   protected Entity(Guid id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }

    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
}
```

The goal is to save data like:

```
|-GrandParent Group
   -Parent Group
   |--Child1 Group
      ---GrandChild1 Group
   |--Child2 Group
       ---GrandChild2 Group
```

**ERROR**

```
{System.InvalidOperationException: No suitable constructor found for entity type 'Group'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type: cannot bind 'guid' in 'Group(Guid guid)'.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConstructorBindingConvention.Apply(InternalModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnModelBuilt(InternalModelBuilder modelBuilder)
```

Could you please let me know how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue has nothing to do with nested collection, but the entity constructor, and is not reproduced with the sample from the question.

But the exception message

> No suitable constructor found for entity type 'Group'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type: cannot bind '**guid**' in 'Group(Guid **guid**)'.

indicates that in your real code you have used

```
public Group(Guid guid):base(guid)
```

The problem is the *name* of the parameter `guid` (instead of `id`). As explained in the [Entity types with constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors) (inside *Some things to note*):

> The parameter types and names must match property types and names, except that properties can be Pascal-cased while the parameters are camel-cased.

In this case, the property is called `Id`, hence the parameter must be called `id` as in the post.